# The [principal] tag has no principle

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just stumbled across the [principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/principal) tag:

> Use this tag for questions related to a principal programming principle.

*Huh?* OK, I'll click to "learn more":

> For example: In Python, a principal programming principle is the EAFP principle. Read about principal in its general meaning in the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/principal).

Well, that didn't clear it up. What is a "principal programming principle", and what qualifies [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) as an example of one? I have never heard of this term, and it seems [Google hasn't either](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22principal%20programming%20principle%22).

There are 158 questions and 7 watchers. Most of the questions seem to be about something called a ["principal"](https://cadse.cs.fiu.edu/corba/corbasec/faq/multi-page/node52.html) in the context of authentication protocols, which seems to mean "a user or application which can authenticate itself". There are also some questions about random other things with the word "principal" in them, as one might expect from a vague tag name, and there are a few about programming principles but seemingly only due to the word "principle" being misspelled.

Surely there is a better name for a tag about the concept "a user or application which can authenticate itself"? I assume there must be an already-existing better-named tag about that concept. Should we:

1. Just fix the tag wiki to be about what people actually use the tag for?
2. Fix the tag wiki and rename the tag to [insert suggestion]?
3. Synonymise the tag with [insert suggestion]?
4. Something else?

Regardless, the questions about random other things and misspellings of "principle" can be cleaned up.

Comment: The [principal] tag has no principle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_(computer_security)

Comment: A cursory glance at the questions list seems to indicate that folks generally agree on what the tag *should* mean, and that it has a reasonable, consistent definition. It's just that the tag wiki disagrees with everyone else. I think it's salvageable; we just need to fix the wiki.

Comment: Tag info reads like someone's idea of a joke.

Comment: @khelwood Maybe instead of seeking permission to make the tag wiki a joke, they figured it was easier to ask forgiveness instead...

Comment: Lol, that Google search truly is case in point. Coincidentally, it *does* reveal [the origins](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32371057#32371057) of the [principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/principles) tag, which [almost had](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13383321) the same tag wiki as this tag, at least at one point.

Comment: A lot of the questions also seem to be about [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

Comment: I'd think "first principles" is shorter, but see zero use for this tag as `design-principles` is probably sufficient.

Comment: I was expecting to find it referring to Kerberos principals (which shouldn't be a tag either way), but this is more ridiculous than that.

Comment: mhh - I've heard of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles - but Id rather have a question pertaining them to have the tagged `[solid-principles]`. Meta questions about "principles" in general sound as if they maybe could be on topic but I wouldn't be able to think of one I would like to ask...

Comment: @PatrickArtner I propose that *"questions about specific principles are OK but questions about meta-principles aren't"* be called Artner's Principle.

Comment: I have a new principle, the KAYA3 principle: naming of meta-principles should be done by third parties using the name sake of the one that proposes it.

Comment: Or perhaps *"What would the school [principal] say?"*

Comment: There is also the [zero-one-infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) principle.

Comment: "Let's make a stand on [principal]"

Comment: The [principal] wants to expel this tag.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with this. This tag makes little sense, except in context of security (where it is an actual, identifiable programming topic). For example, in [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-5.0)

> A principal object represents the security context of the user on whose behalf the code is running, including that user's identity (IIdentity) and any roles to which they belong.

This concept is, of course, more general than just a .NET concept. I include that for illustration that this does actually identify a programming topic. To avoid confusion, maybe we should just rename it to something like [principal-security-entity] (or something to that effect).

A weaker option would be to edit the tag Wiki to state that this is about the security concept and remove the tag from everything other than questions about the security topic.

Comment: Braiam, in comment to the OP, said _"expecting to find it referring to Kerberos principals (which shouldn't be a tag either way),"_, which is totally true, but that's because Kerberos principals (and the .NET example) are specific implementations of the general security concept. So, +1 for keeping a tag specifically for security principals.

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that none of the questions on the tag seems to refer to the general security concept either.